# Passing std::function as parameter to lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, lambda

How execute code in function lambda parameter?

```
auto lambda = [] (std::function<void(std::string,std::string)>) { //run function, work with string parameters };

std::function<void(std::string, std::string)> work = [](std::string, std::string) {};

lambda(work);
```

Comment: I'm confused. Do you understand how to use std::function outside of a lambda?

Comment: `auto lambda = [] (std::function<void(std::string,std::string)> f) { f("a", "b"); };`  Is this what you are looking for? It's pretty straightforward, not clear where you see the difficulty.

Comment: Very simple, had not realized. Thank you.